# Chaining of responsibility pattern takes different parameter types?

Tags: java, design-patterns, chaining

I've read the [chain of the responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), the examples are nothing but normal printing. What if I'd like to chaining more difficult operations together,  for instance,  there's some use case in real life:

Taking a request, 
request ->  Handler 1 (request, Integer)  -> Handler 2 (Integer, String) -> Handler 3 (String, Long),

in which each handler takes some input of parameter, and generate output in another parameter type. Can we chain such handlers together using **Generic** idea?

```html
public abstract class Handler <Input, Output> {
    public void setSuccessor(Handler handler);
    public abstract Output handleRequest(Input in);
}
```

I hope I clarify the problems clearly enough.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a chain of responsibility, each element of the chain has to be set up with the next element, so it has to know up front what the interface should be. In a lot of cases a context is being passed around.

Are you sure you don't have a sequence at hand, where handler two is depending on the result of handler 1 to do its work? If so the chain of responsibility is not going to work out.

A chain of responsibility is used when at compile time, you have no idea which steps will be necessary, but for example when they come from configuration.